# How can I get the USB Port Number in Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, usb, iokit, darwin

I found out one class `IORegistryEntry` in IOKit. It has APIs to get the values of the properties. I am trying to use this class, but I am not able to compile.

I have added IOKit and Kernel Frameworks. It throws an compilation error saying:

> IORegistryEntry not declared.

If anybody knows how to compile, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the relevant header file?

```
#include <IOKit/IORegistryEntry.h>
```

If you have and you're still getting errors, please provide more details.